# Authenticating for Youtube Data API v3 without opening a browser (Python)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to build a simple upload application for personal use. The reason why I am posting is the google documentation and the stack overflow posts on this subject are rather confusing for a person new to google API's. Ive already went through the google cloud setup involving creating a secret key and a client id (client_secret.json)

My problem is that I want to be able to run through the o-auth2 authentication flow to gain access to the API without opening a browser. This is because the script will live on a headless Ubuntu server once complete.

Ive already read some posts about refresh tokens and access tokens in the follow posts

[YouTube Data API v3: video upload from server without opening the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61851000/youtube-data-api-v3-video-upload-from-server-without-opening-the-browser)

[How to refresh an access token for the youtube-data-api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359051/how-to-refresh-an-access-token-for-the-youtube-data-api-v3)

Ive also read some google documentation

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#OAuth2_Refreshing_a_Token

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps

These articles helped me understand whats going on but they are not actionable as it seems like the google documentation is fragmented/out of date.

This is my code that comes from the get started guide. I only had to change 1 function to get it to run.

```py
import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
     # Was flow.run_console but that method was deprecated so I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602866/google-oauth-attributeerror-installedappflow-object-has-no-attribute-run-co
    credentials = flow.run_local_server(open_browser=False)
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.channels().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
        mine=True
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code runs but when I click the link generated in the output I get a redirect error but that's not important to overall issue of being unable to authenticate without a browser.

Comment: Part 1: Google authentication is performed in the browser. You cannot bypass that for Google OAuth. You must use a browser to fetch user OAuth tokens. For machine authentication, Google provides service accounts, which are part of Google Cloud, but I have not written code using service accounts and YouTube. Tip: Google Cloud services and Google services are different. YouTube is not part of Google Cloud.

Comment: Part 2: Some of your links talk about OAuth Refresh Tokens. Those tokens are used to refresh OAuth Access Tokens. You must use a browser to fetch the refresh token. Then you can get new access tokens without the browser. However, refresh tokens expire and are often invalidated. When that happens you must launch a new browser authentication session. In summary, Google has tightened security and will prevent you from bypassing browser authentication to access data stored in Google and in some cases will require you to complete an expensive security audit of your application.

Comment: Part 3: ***The YouTube Data API supports the service account flow only for YouTube content owners that own and manage multiple YouTube channels. Specifically, content owners can use service accounts to call API methods that support the onBehalfOfContentOwner request parameter***. [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps) Using service accounts does not require the browser for authentication.

Comment: This [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#using-oauth-2.0-for-server-side,-standalone-scripts) might also be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the info! It seems my best bet is to use the service account so I'm going to try and use that.

Comment: This part of the wording is not clear to me: ***that own and manage multiple YouTube channels***. That might affect you for a single-user account.

Comment: certain yt videos have restrictions so you cant use it anonymously with API's, you have to provide your google oauth creds to basically use it.

Comment: My only option now is to run an o-auth2 pipeline on my computer then pipe the result of that along with a refresh token into the remote server that would execute the calls. Then I would do the authentication as need. Does this make sense?

Comment: I would save the token(s) in a JSON file in Google Cloud Storage. When your other software needs to run, it reads the file from Google Cloud Storage. That way you can periodically recreate the tokens via browser authentication and your other program will automatically use the latest saved tokens.

Comment: Which tokens should I save in the JSON File and how long will an access token last?

Comment: The access token is valid for 3,600 seconds (one hour). The refresh token, which can create (request) access tokens, does not have a defined invalidation time. Typically, a refresh token lasts a week or two but can be invalidated at any time for many reasons.

Comment: @jgore200377 I believe the refresh token is the way to go for your use case (even if it expires after some time). That's also my situation. Have you tried that? In any case, whatever solution you find, please post your answer below. thank you.